# Can I buy Final Cut Pro X 10.3.4

Tags: final-cut-pro

I have an older Macbook that is stuck on El Capitan. I want to **purchase** Final Cut Pro X at the app store and install the version 10.3.4, which is the last version that supports El Cap.

Is it possible using my Mac?  Or do I need to

1. borrow a friends (newer) computer
2. purchanse FCPX using **my apple id**
3. install on my friends computer
4. and then... install it on my computer ??

Will that work?

Comment: If you have Catalina, I don't see how you can't answer this yourself? Go to the App Store, try to buy Final Cut. If you can't, you'll have to use a Mac with a newer OS, buy it with your AppleID, then go back to your machine and download it from the "Purchased" section. The App Store will then offer you the latest version that runs on your version of macOS.

Comment: ok thanks @KevinGrabher. I was hesitant because It seems risky. Maybe i get to step 4 and it won't let me install it, then I've lost $299. right?

Comment: Are you familiar with Final Cut X? I strongly recommend avoiding it, it's a clumsy software made by fools for fools. I only use it because I have no choice. If you can't afford paying for Adobe Premiere, use Black Magic's free DaVince Resolve. It is a complete solution, without the FCPX awful interface. Both support older versions. Some users will say "you have to adapt", "it's clever", blablabla. But no. They are wrong. You don't have to change from simple methods established decades ago, because some smart ass at Apple have decided you should. You will thank me later.

Comment: @MateusRibeiro thanks, you are right. I am using Davinci now and it is everything i need.